# Python Pandas Merge and Append Data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge data from 2 dataframes where df_revised updates values for same column/row, but then also keep columns from df that didn't exist in df_revised and struggling to accomplish this. PARID should be the index. (There will never be PARIDs in one df different from another.)

**df**

```
PARID   A   B   C
100     2   3   99
101     1   3   84
```

**df_revised**

```
PARID   A   B
100     33  44
101     10  33
```

**Desired Output**

```
PARID   A   B   C
100     33  44  99
101     10  33  84
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
C = df[df['PARID','C']]
df_revised = df_revised.merge(C,on = 'PARID')
```

Comment: This worked really well and I just forgot to mark this the right answer and vote you up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_revised.join(df['C'])
```

Output:

```
PARID   A   B   C            
100    33  44  99
101    10  33  84
```

Answer (score 0):

Using update

```
df1.update(df2)
df1
Out[64]: 
        A   B   C
PARID            
100    33  44  99
101    10  33  84
```

Comment: should we mark this question as dup? there are many ways to do this but it's essentially 'how do I join in pandas' no?

Comment: @Yuca maybe it is a dup . :-) , if you find it I will mark it done .

Answer (score 0):

Using [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) you can do it with:

```
df_revised.merge(df[['PARID','C']], on='PARID')

#    A   B  PARID   C
#0  33  44    100  99
#1  10  33    101  84
```